# Java program to find the number of combinations that four cards in a deck will equal 24

Tags: java

I have a program in Java that will take a deck of cards and calculate the number of combinations of four cards will equal 24. So far, I have this:

```
public class Assign5b {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] deck = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
            1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
            1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
            1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13};

        int total;
        total = calculate(deck);
        output(total);
    }

    public static int calculate(int[] deck) {
        int total = 0;
        int stack1, stack2, stack3, stack4, accumulate;

        for (stack1 = 0; stack1 < 52; stack1++) {
            for (stack2 = (stack1 + 1); stack2 < 52; stack2++) {
                for (stack3 = (stack2 + 1); stack3 < 52; stack3++) {
                    for (stack4 = (stack3 + 1); stack4 < 52; stack4++) {
                        accumulate = (deck[stack1] + deck[stack2] + deck[stack3] + deck[stack4]);
                        if (accumulate == 24)
                            total++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }       
        return total;
    }   

    public static void output(int total){
        System.out.println ("The total number of card combinations of 4 that \n" + "equal 24 is: " + total);
    }
}
```

So my problem is not that it doesn't run, or that it's not displaying the correct value, but it's those nested loops. I don't want them there. It's making it run really inefficiently and I know there's a better way to get it to run I just can't visualize it.

Answer (score 0):

You could add checks at the beginning of each loop to see if the running total already be over 24.  In this case, there would be no point in doing those loops anyway:

```
public static int calculate(int[] deck, int target) {
    int total = 0;
    int stack1, stack2, stack3, stack4, accumulate;

    for (stack1 = 0; stack1 < 52; stack1++) {
        if (deck[stack1] > target) break;

        for (stack2 = (stack1 + 1); stack2 < 52; stack2++) {
            if (deck[stack1] + deck[stack2] > target) break;

            for (stack3 = (stack2 + 1); stack3 < 52; stack3++) {
                if (deck[stack1] + deck[stack2] + deck[stack3] > target) break;

                for (stack4 = (stack3 + 1); stack4 < 52; stack4++) {
                    if (deck[stack1] + deck[stack2] + deck[stack3] + deck[stack4] > target) break;
                    accumulate = (deck[stack1] + deck[stack2] + deck[stack3] + deck[stack4]);
                    if (accumulate == 24)
                        total++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return total;
}
```

This assumes that your `deck` is sorted in *ascending* order, e.g.

```
int[] deck = {1, 1, 1, 1,
              2, 2, 2, 2,
              ...
              13, 13, 13, 13};
```

Comment: I don't follow your reasoning. What does target get initialized as?

Comment: Target would get initialized to 24. This doesn't work unless you re-order the array in ascending order, though. It will cause the loop to break before the array wraps around to 1.

Comment: @JacobPorter The parameter `target` is whatever total you want, e.g. 24

Comment: also, when you say that you wouldn't need the loops, how do you mean? I can't really tell how to do it. At this point, obviously you can tell it's for an assignment, but I've already submitted my working code, so my grade is locked in anyway, I'm just looking to possibly make it run better by getting rid of the nested loops.

Comment: @WillKaczmarek Yes, I will add a note that this assumes the deck sorted in ascending order.  Sorting a small array is trivial and not affect the overall running time.